# Trouble getting items from some messy elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python in combination with `BeautifulSoup` to scrape `addresses` from some `html elements`. The `addresses` are separated by `br` tags, so I can't get all them using `next_sibling`. I've tried with two different approaches to reach them. However, the latter one is slightly close. I am still unsure as to what should be the efficient approach to get the `addresses` like the way I've pasted below in my expected output. Thanks in advance.

`Elements` within which the `addresses` lies:

```
<div class="item-listing">
    <h4><a href="/alps/" target="_blank">AK</a></h4>
    5200 A St Ste 102<br>
    Anchorage, AK 99518<br>

    Phone: (907) 563-9333
    <br>
    <ul class="list-items" style="margin-top: 5px;">
        <li style="padding: 3px; background: #efefef; border-radius: 4px;"><img src="/images/icon-rec.png" style="height: 24px; width: 24px;" alt="Rl" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Sales"></li>
    </ul>
    <a style="margin-right: 10px;" href="http://www.alps.com/?" target="_blank">Website</a>
    <a href="/al/anchorage/" target="_blank">Profile</a>
</div>
```

What I've tried so far with:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml") #here content holding the elements above
for items in soup.select(".item-listing"):
    addr = [item.next_sibling for item in items.select("h4")]
    # addr = [item.string for item in items.select_one("h4").next_siblings if not item.name=="a"]
    print(addr)
```

Result of first `addr` (from the script):

```
['\n    5200 A St Ste 102']
```

Result of commented out `addr`:

```
['\n    5200 A St Ste 102', None, '\n    Anchorage, AK 99518', None, '\n        \n    Phone: (907) 563-9333\n    ', None, '\n', None, '\n', '\n', '\n']
```

My expected output (or very close to this):

```
5200 A St Ste 102 Anchorage, AK 99518 Phone: (907) 563-9333
```

Comment: To skip over the `None` values, you just need to add `and item.string` to the condition. If you want to strip out all the extraneous whitespace and join up with spaces, you can just do `' '.join(part.strip() for part in part)`.

Comment: Normally you could just use [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) to do most of the work, but since this HTML is a screwy mess where there is no `div` or other structural or even layout tag holding the address without other irrelevant stuff, there’s no way out of being a little messy.

Comment: It's not a workaround but a suggestion to fetch the same output (less painfully) for `addr` using `addr = [item.string for item in items.children if not item.name=="a"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just need to update your list comprehension to account for the whitespace and `None` values.

Try this instead:

```
addr = [item.string.strip() for item in items.select_one("h4").next_siblings if item and item.string and not item.name=="a"]`
```

Using `item.string.strip()` will get rid of the extra whitespace and `\n`.
Adding `if item` will filter out the `None` values.

This should result in

```
['5200 A St Ste 102', 'Anchorage, AK 99518', 'Phone: (907) 563-9333']
```

You can join the elements that aren't empty:

```
' '.join([a for a in addr if a])
```

which will result in

```
'5200 A St Ste 102 Anchorage, AK 99518 Phone: (907) 563-9333'
```

Comment: I tried several times to execute your suggested portion but I encounter this error: `addr = [strip(item.string) for item in items.select_one("h4").next_siblings if item and not item.name=="a"]
NameError: name 'strip' is not defined`

Comment: Whoops, sorry! Updated!

Comment: Sorry dear, you can't do so I meant, you can't apply `.strip()` on generators. It is not a valid approach. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Okay, dear. However, `item.string` is not a generator, it's a `str` and yes, you can apply them in generators. Why would you not be able to? The above code is working for me.

Comment: Now it is working like a charm. `if item.string` did the trick. Accepted and upvoted. Thanks a lot.